# android use intent with class.forName

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have the String names of the classes in an ArrayList.

If i try to call the Intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MultipleChoice.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
```

It works without problems, but when i wanna do it like this, i get a `ClassFoundException`.
In `config.getTests(config.getPage()))` i get `"MultipleChoice"` returned.

```
try {
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, Class.forName(config.getTests(config.getPage())));
  context.startActivity(intent);
  context.finish();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Why is it like this?

Comment: I hope the error you are getting is ClassNotFoundException, not ClassFoundException.

Comment: I think config.getTests(....) should class name with package, for example com.xyz.MultipleChoice. You may try hardcoding this in Class.forName(..) first. If it works, then you can find a way to get it from config.getTest(....)

Comment: bla.bla.bla.full.name.with.package.is.needed.MultipleChoice ... edit: damn you thinksteep ... you were first :)

Comment: I have posted it as answer. Please accept.

Comment: @thinksteep Its new in java 1.7. It explodes every time it finds a class.

Comment: @sfratini: Sorry! didn't get you.

Comment: @thinksteep It was a joke about the "I hope the error you are getting is ClassNotFoundException, not ClassFoundException". It will be a little problem if Java start throwing an Exception every time it finds a class:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `config.getTests(....)` should class name with package, for example `com.xyz.MultipleChoice`. You may try hardcoding this in `Class.forName(..)` first. If it works, then you can find a way to get it from `config.getTest(....)`